# What is time complexity of maximum bipartitie matching algorithm?

Tags: matching, bipartite

Here is the classical problem : - "There are M job applicants and N jobs. Each applicant has a subset of jobs that he/she is interested in. Each job opening can only accept one applicant and a job applicant can be appointed for only one job. Find an assignment of jobs to applicants in such that as many applicants as possible get jobs."

I am using the following code and algorithm to solve the problem : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

What will be the time complexity of this algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm#Complexity) Wikipedia article, the algorithm by Ford & Fulkerson has a runtime complexity of `O(|E|f)`, where `|E|` is the cardinality of the input's edge set. Note that this runtime bound depends on the optimal value and is pseudo-polynomial.